# Reusing NSMutableString correctly on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablestring, stringwithformat

Using objective-c on the iPhone, what is wrong with this code?
Is it leaking memory?  Why?
How would I do this correctly?

```
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"the value is %d", i];
```

... then later in my code... I might need to change this to:

```
result = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"the value is now %d", i];
```

I need to use stringWithFormat a 2nd time... but isn't that creating a NEW string and not correctly freeing the old one?

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't leak memory because `stringWithFormat:` returns an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the instance method "setString" for your already existing NSMutableString, like this:

```
[ result setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"the value is now %d", i] ];
```

Comment: Assuming you mean `[NSString stringWithFormat`, which misses the point entirely: it creates a new string and then copies its contents to the mutable string, instead of simply reusing the memory of the mutable string.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to reuse the string, you can use something like

```
[result setString:@""];
[result appendFormat:@"the value is now %d", i];
```

However, unless you notice a performance/memory problem, just use

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the value is %d", i];

/* ... */

result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the value is now %d", i];
```

It's generally easier to work with immutable objects because they can't change under your feet.

Answer (score -1):

What you have seems to me to be the natural way to replace a mutable string with new content, *unless* you have other references to the same mutable string elsewhere.

If you *don't* have other references to it and you are reusing the string only to improve performance/memory footprint, that sounds like premature optimisation.

By the way, you do not own a string you obtain via stringWithFormat: so you do not need to (Indeed must not) release it.